# How to duplicate column and split another column based on delimiter using awk or sed?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a large input file that looks like the following:

```
VARIANTS        SAMPLES
chr1:10583:G:A  HSB100
chr1:10583:G:A  HSB105
chr1:10583:G:A  HSB107
chr1:10583:G:A  HSB121
chr1:10583:G:A  HSB122
```

What I need it to look like is:

```
CHROM   POS     ID              REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO
chr1    10583   chr1:10583:G:A  G   A   .    .      HSB100
chr1    10583   chr1:10583:G:A  G   A   .    .      HSB105
chr1    10583   chr1:10583:G:A  G   A   .    .      HSB107
chr1    10583   chr1:10583:G:A  G   A   .    .      HSB121
chr1    10583   chr1:10583:G:A  G   A   .    .      HSB122
```

Basically, I need to duplicate the first column of the input (which will become the `ID` column), and then split the original column based on the ':' delimiter into those new columns. I had written a python script to do this, but it's using too much memory. The `QUAL` and `FILTER` columns are just dummy columns where all the rows are `.`. How can I get this desired output using something like awk or sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting on the colon in $1 the output can be generated using:

```
$ awk '{split($1,s,":"); print s[1],s[2],$1,s[3],s[4],".",".",$2;}' file.txt
chr1 10583 chr1:10583:G:A G A . . HSB100
chr1 10583 chr1:10583:G:A G A . . HSB105
chr1 10583 chr1:10583:G:A G A . . HSB107
chr1 10583 chr1:10583:G:A G A . . HSB121
chr1 10583 chr1:10583:G:A G A . . HSB122
```

Comment: minus one for the way you handle the file, use what Ed writes. Edit your post and give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^((.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)) /\2 \3 \1\4 \5. . /' file
```

Pattern match and back references.